# String sent via text changing byte array value

Tags: android, arrays, networking

I'm trying to confirm a user's phone number by sending the a text to the user's phone then getting it and matching the number the user gave and the number the text just came from...problem is that although the text matches 100%, I've confirmed in a lot of ways, the byte arrays do not match therefore the "phone numbers" do not match, and the confirmation isn't possible. Is this a real thing: values sent via a network changing byte arrays?

Text sent:

```
String user_phone_number = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
String number = "" + user_phone_number;
String verificationCode = "717345221";
String message = verificationCode + user_phone_number;
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

Text recieved:

```
if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msgFrom;
        if (bundle != null) {
            try {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    msgFrom = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    String verificationCode = "717345221";

                    if (msgBody.startsWith(verificationCode)) {
                        msgBody = msgBody.substring(verificationCode
                                .length());

                        if (msgBody.trim() == msgFrom.trim()) {
                            showCorrectNotification(context);
                            try {
                                Intent o = new Intent(context,
                                        ProfileInformation.class);
                                o.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                context.startActivity(o);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.toString();
                            }
   }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Are you comparing strings? Maybe an encoding thing?

Comment: Please provide your code where you compare the values

Comment: Yeah...I'm comparing two strings...elaborate on how it could be encoding?

Comment: You need to know what sort of encoding both ends use. My guess is that either your program or the text is encoded in something other than ASCII or UTF, because these should in theory be equivalent.

Comment: The text is sent and recieved by the same app..and the bytearrays are the same only for the last 5 values...which change even if the actual text values remain the same

Comment: Posting code in a bit

Comment: The trim() method tells me spaces aren't the problem using substring() makes msgBody == msgFrom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare Strings like this:

```
msgBody.trim() == msgFrom.trim()
```

You should use:

```
msgBody.trim().equals(msgFrom.trim())
```